# Android: Get Google Docs files pogramatically

Tags: android, authentication

I'm creating an android project that will allow the user to get Google Docs and I don't know where to start. Could someone help me with the basics?

Answer (score 1):

Start here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/